# How to update table based on status in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a table function to add item from another table in the same database. The table are `pekerjaan` and `personil` (both of this table is in eloquent relationship (OneToOne)), in the table `personil` it has a column `status`, I set the default value for the `status` as **tersedia**. And in the table `pekerjaan` the user can add item from the `personil` table based on the `status` if the `status` is **tersedia** then it will allow the user to add and change the `personil's status` to **tdkTersedia**. If the user tried to add item with status **tdkTersedia**, the page will return an error saying that it is not available. **How to achieve this?**

Here is what I've tried in the AdminController:

```
public function update_personilpekerjaan(Request $request, $id){    
        $personil = Personil::find($id);     
        if($personil->status != 'tersedia'){
            return redirect()->back();
        }else{
            $pekerjaan = Pekerjaan::find($id);
            $pekerjaan->personil_id=$request->personil_id;
            $personil->status='tdkTersedia';
            $pekerjaan->update();
            $personil->save();

            return redirect()->route('datapekerjaan')->with('message','Personil Pekerjaan Berhasil diupdate!');
        }   
    }
```

And here is my form where the user add item from `personil` table

```
(...)
<div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Personil Pekerjaan</label>
              <select name="personil_id" class="form-control select2bs4" style="width: 50%;">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Pilih Personil</option>
                @foreach ($personil as $personils)
                <option value="{{$personils->id}}">
                  {{$personils->nama}}
                </option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
</div>
(...)
```

Here is the table view for `personil` table

```
<tbody>
                      @php $no = 1; @endphp
                      @foreach ($personil as $personils)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$no++}}</td>
                        <td>{{$personils->nama}}</a></td>
                        <td>{{$personils->lahirtgl}}</td>
                        <td>{{$personils->pendidikan}}</td>
                        <td>{{$personils->pengalaman}}</td>
                        <td>{{$personils->keahlian}}</td>
                        @if ($personils->status == 'tersedia')
                          <td class="text-success">Tersedia</td>
                        @elseif($personils->status == 'tdkTersedia')
                          <td>{{$personils->pekerjaan}}</td>
                        @endif
                        
                        <td>
                            <a href="/editpersonil/{{$personils->id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Edit</a>
                            <a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delete" data-id="{{$personils->id}}" data-nama="{{$personils->nama}}">Hapus</a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                    </tbody>
```

Here is the relationship

```
Personil.php
class Personil extends Eloquent
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function pekerjaans(){
       return $this->hasOne(Pekerjaan::class);
   }
}

Pekerjaan.php
class Pekerjaan extends Eloquent
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $dates = ['tanggal'];

    public function penyedia(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Penyedia::class, 'penyedia_id');
   }

   public function jeniskerja(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Jeniskerja::class, 'jeniskerja_id');
   }

   public function personil(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Personil::class, 'personil_id');
   }

   public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On store method just add if statement

```
if(auth()->user()->personil()->status == 'whatYouNeed') {
// code goes here
} else {
return abort(403);
}
```

Or just create [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#creating-policies).